# How to read messages in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a bot for Discord to stream my radio/podcasts however I'm stuck. I'm trying to get the bot to send the list of stations from the ./stations file as you can see from the code below.

From the line

```js
if(command == 'stations') {
    message.channel.createMessage(``); // Stuck at this point.
```

I have tried this method but the text file content is not defined.

```js
{message.channel.createMessage(open("./stations.txt").readlines());
```

So the command is !stations it should return with the list of stations from the txt file.

```js
const Eris = require('eris');
const client = new Eris(require('./config.json').token, {
  maxShards: 1
});
fs = require('fs')
var stations = fs.readFileSync("./stations.txt", {
  "encoding": "utf-8"
});


client.connect();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready to go!')
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith('!')) {
    let command = message.content.substring(1).split(" ")[0];
    let args = message.content.substring(2 + command.length);

    if (command == 'stations') {
      message.channel.createMessage(`STUCK AT THIS POINT`);
    } else if (command == 'radio') {
      if (args == '') 
        return message.channel.createMessage(`Please specify the radio station example: **!radio <station name>**`);

      if (require('./stations.json')[args]) {
        if (!message.member.voiceState) 
          return message.channel.createMessage(`:warning: **You need to be in a voice channel.**`);
        client.joinVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID).then(vc => {
          if (vc.playing) 
            vc.stopPlaying();

          message.channel.createMessage(`:radio: You are now streaming **${args}**.`);
          vc.play(require('./stations.json')[args]);
        })
      } else {
        return message.channel.createMessage(`**Cannot find a radio station with that name.** Make sure it has capitals and the correct spelling. See pinned messages for stream list.`);

      }
    }
  }
})
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: using the stations var doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, or I must be doing something wrong here and I can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: well, make sure there are no errors in your server console... I don't see anything wrong

Comment: What version of node are you using? There's a better solution that's just as easy to integrate as the currently accepted answer if your version supports `async` / `await`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way to read a text file into a variable in node.js is

```
fs.readFileSync(path, options).toString()
```

you already have this in your code at the top where you are assigning the `stations` variable, just add the `.toString()` call (eventually add further text processing, like `.replace(/\n/g, ', ')` to replace newlines with commas) and use the `stations` variable where needed. You can use try/catch to check there were some errors reading the file.

**Reference:** [NodeJS - fs readfilesync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

Comment: The `.toString()` call is unnecessary when the `encoding` option is specified, since that causes the return value to already be a string instead of a buffer.